# How to select only first column dynamically on mysql

Tags: mysql, select, mysql-5

I have to select only first column. Because of i dont want to select all columns like `SELECT * FROM table`. But my first columns may vary like following:

```
id
article_id
user_id
product_id
page_id
etc..
```

Is there any way always getting only first column. For example:

```
SELECT 0 FROM table;

or

SELECT FIRST_COLUMN FROM table;
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear why you need this but technically you can do it with dynamic SQL like this

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT column_name 
  INTO @sql
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE table_schema = SCHEMA()
   AND table_name = 'users'
   AND ordinal_position = 1;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT `', @sql, '` FROM users');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1fd72/2)** demo

---

You can wrap it up into a stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE select_first_column(IN _tname VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
  SET @sql = NULL;
  SELECT column_name 
    INTO @sql
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
   WHERE table_schema = SCHEMA()
     AND table_name = _tname
     AND ordinal_position = 1;

  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT `', @sql, '` FROM `', _tname, '`');

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Sample usage:

```
CALL select_first_column('users');
CALL select_first_column('orders');
```

Sample output:

```
| USER_ID |
|---------|
|       1 |
|       2 |

| ORDER_ID |
|----------|
|      101 |
|      202 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e95d5/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL you can do it using column aliasing:

```
postgres=# CREATE TABLE product (product_id INTEGER, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE

postgres=# INSERT INTO product (product_id, name) VALUES (1, 'product 1'), (2, 'product 2');
INSERT 0 2

postgres=# SELECT p.id FROM product p (id);
 id 
----
  1
  2
(2 rows)
```

Don't know if it works the same way in MySQL, though.